# Deploy React app in vercel with backend in render

Tags: reactjs, django, deployment, vercel, netlify

I was trying to deploy my vite react application in vercel. I hosted it's backend part in render, Now backend is working, but when i hosted in frontend, the request URL change to hosted URL because I used vite proxy to use shortcut URL but it's not working in devlopment,

Example of my vite config

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VitePWA(manifestForPlugin),
    react(),
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://sample__.onrender.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace("/api", ""),
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://mydomain.onrender.com/", 
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace("/api", ""),
      }
    }
  }
});
```

so when i call api my url is like:
`api/auth/login/`

so in localhost, it will became, `localhost:8000/auth/login/`

but when i did it from dev server of vercel it become like  `mydomain.onrender.com/api/auth/login/`

In localhost my backend is running in 8000 and frontend is running in 5173

Comment: I'm not certain as to why you are saying it became vercel/netlify/url/api/login/. If your api endpoint in your dev server was api/auth/login/ and it was working correctly, I would think it should still be https://www.yourdomain.com/api/auth/login

Comment: sorry,
yes it becomes like mydomain/api/auth/login. 

you have any idea about how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vercel rewrites as a reverse proxy, you can refer to the docs [here](https://vercel.com/guides/vercel-reverse-proxy-rewrites-external)